# Dimension of subspace 10x10

Tags: linear-algebra

Question:

Let $W$ be the subspace of a $M_{10,10}$ consisting of all matrices whose diagonal entries are zero. Find the dimension of $W$.

Not really sure how to approach this. Any suggestions?

Comment: $$10x10-10=100-10=90$${}{}{}{}

Comment: Have you learnt the Rank-Nullity theorem yet?

Answer (score 0):

Intuitively, the dimension of $M_{10,10}$ is $100$ because you need to specify all $100$ entries to determine a matrix uniquely. All the matrices in $W$ have zeros on the diagonal, so we need only specify the other $90$ non-diagonal entries. Therefore, the dimension is $90$.

I admit this argument is not completely rigorous but hopefully will give you the intuition needed to write a rigorous proof.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:

Consider the linear map $\;\begin{aligned}[t]f:\mathcal M_{10\times 10}&\longrightarrow K^{10}, \\ (a_{ij})_{1\le i,j\le 10}&\longmapsto(a_{ii})_{1\le i\le 10} \end{aligned}$

Observe that $f$ is onto and $W=\ker f$.